# How to access icloud.com on Chrome for Android?

Tags: icloud, android, web-browser

Apple refuses to load icloud.com on Chrome for Android.  Instead of showing the login form, the page displays a message stating that "Your browser is not supported".

How can I bypass this restriction?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59950/discussion-on-question-by-augurar-how-to-access-icloud-com-via-mobile-browser).

Comment: I've cleared the close votes and moved the meta discussion to chat. This seems quite OK to have on the site - I even voted up the answer / question. It might be duplicate of another question - but it's clearly on topic as edited (thanks Tom)

Comment: It's probably a safe bet to assume the initial down-votes were due to the rant towards Apple in the original unedited post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This restriction can be bypassed by changing your browser's user agent.  This can be done by clicking the "..." menu and selecting "Request desktop site".  Apparently Apple only blocks Chrome for Android, not for desktop.

References:

- [New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2016/06/09/technology/personaltech/when-android-meets-icloud.html)
- [USA Today](https://www.usatoday.com/story/tech/columnist/2014/07/20/chrome-browser-and-icloud/12748131/)